# Can't execute binary in FUSE with `exec format error`

Tags: permissions, filesystem, fuse

I am using a FUSE with mount options `default_permissions,allow_other,ro,exec`. If I execute a binary present under root of FUSE, it is giving error

```
bash: exec format error: binary_name
```

FUSE debug log shows that it file is read correctly.

- I am able to execute the same binary if it is not placed in fuse.

  So I think arch is compatible.
- I am able to execute a binary with same mount options if I pass every call to fuse to underlying files like [this](https://github.com/fuse4x/fuse/blob/master/example/fusexmp.c).

  So I think mount options are also should be okay.
- Following are options from `findmnt` output for my FUSE:

  ```
  ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=771069,group_id=89939,default_permisions,allow_other
  ```
- Following is file permissions for binary:

  ```
  -rwxr-x--- 1 771069 89939 5.8M Nov 8 23:45 binary_name
  ```

Following are outputs of `file` command if that helps:

- When binary is accessed from fuse: i.e. `file /path_to_mount_point/path_to_binary`

> ELF 64-bit LSB no file type, no machine, invalid version (SYSV)

- When binary is accessed without fuse: i.e.`file /path_to_binary`

> ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=28ba79c778f7402713aec6af319ee0fbaf3a8014, stripped

- Output of `ldd /path_to_mount_point/path_to_binary`

> not a dynamic executable

- Output of `ldd /path_to_binary`

> linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0dbfb000)
> libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0cb6722000)
> libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0cb6705000)
> libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0cb6540000)
> /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0cb674a000)

I am not able to figure out what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant but there is an s missing in `default_permisions`.

Comment: Add the output of `file binary_name` and `ldd binary_name`, please. And which FUSE filesystem is it?

Comment: @muru dded output of `file` and `ldd` commands